# How to keep focused row when sorting an ASPxGridview?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

It is quite common to use the `ASPxGridView` event `OnFocusedRowChanged` to filter data from other components on the screen.

The problem is, when the table is sorted, the property `FocusedRowIndex` is kept by changing the `KeyValue` and consequently losing the argument filter we use.

How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `ASPxGridView` is sorted, a [callback runs](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18387).

To avoid the problem, just handle the `AfterPerformCallback` server-side event with the following code:

```
int rowIndex = (sender as ASPxGridView).FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue(keyValue);
(sender as ASPxGridView).FocusedRowIndex = (rowIndex == ASPxGridView.InvalidRowIndex) ? -1 : rowIndex;
```

I'll explain: keep the value of `KeyValue` used to filter the data of the other components on the screen in `Session` or in an `ASPxHiddenField`.

If the value of `keyValue` is not found, we set the `FocusedRowIndex` to -1 (which unfocus the row), otherwise we always keep the same `keyValue` focused.